# httpClientTestingModule mock

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

I've got function

```
delete(event, envName) {
event.stopPropagation();
this.toogleBtn(event);
this.modal.show('Confirm',  envName ).then(() => {
  this.http.delete(myAddress + envName, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer token}`)
  }).subscribe(response => {
    this.getDetails().then(res => {
      this.details = res;
    });
  });
});
}
```

and I want to use httpClientTestingModule to mock http request, like that:

```
it('should delete', () => {
  const event = new Event('click');
  const envName = 'env';
  spyOn(component, 'toogleBtn');
  spyOn(event, 'stopPropagation');
  spyOn(component.modal, 'show').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
  component.deleteEvnBtn(event, envName);
  const req = httpClientMock.expectOne(myAddress + envName);
  req.flush('data');
});
```

but I received an error in the line with httpClientMock.expectOne:

Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: myAddressWithEnvName", found none.

where address is exactly the same as in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Either your test should be `async` or your `then`method is not being called.